# SSRS Running Values with an IIF Statement Issues

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am developing an SSRS report and am having trouble with an expression. I want to apply 1 IIF statement with 2 conditions to a cell in a table. I am correctly do this, but the first expression only gives me the First value in the dataset. I took out the 'First' in the expression and tried to apply the RunningValue but i am getting stuck. I get an #Error in the cell. It just says #Error. How to apply the same IIF statement but loop through all the values in the dataset?

Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong? All I am trying to do is apply a statement and if it meets the conditions then return only the value without summing. Any help is most appreciated.

First Script that works only for the first value.

```
=IIF(First(Fields!Title.Value, "getData")=1 And First(Fields!Day.Value, "getData")=DateAdd("d",-6,Parameters!WeekEnding.Value),Fields!Value.Value, "")
```

Second script trying to apply the RunningValue

```
=RunningValue(IIF(Fields!Title.Value=1 And Fields!Day.Value=DateAdd("d",-11,Parameters!WeekEnding.Value),Fields!Value.Value, ""),Sum,"getData")
```

Dataset query:

```
SELECT 
    a.PkId, a.EmpId, a.WkEnd, a.Day, a.Title, a.Description,
    a.Value as Val 
FROM 
    EmployeeTimeSheets a  
INNER JOIN 
    Employees b ON a.EmpId = b.RowID
WHERE 
    Employee = @SelectEmployee 
    AND (WkEnd >= @WeekEnding OR WkEnd <= @WeekEnding)
```

DataSet

[image]

SQL table

[image]

SSRS table

[image]

Desired results

[image]

Comment: What is your tablix dataset called? Is it getData?

Comment: Yes, the dataset is called getData

Comment: Try this `=RunningValue(IIF(Fields!Title.Value=1 And Fields!Day.Value=DateAdd("d",-11,Parameters!WeekEnding.Value),Fields!Value.Value, 0.0),Sum,Nothing)`

Comment: ''Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel.Field'.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2005Impl.SetReportDefinition(String Report, Byte[] Definition, Guid batchId, Warning[]& Warnings)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2010Impl.SetItemDefinition(String ItemPath, Byte[] Definition, String expectedItemTypeName, Property[] Properties, Warning[]& Warnings)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010.SetItemDefinition(String ItemPath, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, Warning[]& Warnings)

Comment: this is what I got when I switched the expression

Comment: Remove the Running value Try this `=IIF(Fields!Title.Value=1 And Fields!Day.Value=DateAdd("d",-11,Parameters!WeekEnding.Value),Fields!Value.Value‌​, 0.0)`

Comment: How are you building the report? Are you using BIDS to create the report?

Comment: I am using Report Builder.. I am getting the same error. Textbox18 contains an error [BC30456]'Value' is not a member of Microsft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing

Comment: Looks like `Value` is not part of your getData dataset. Also remember SSRS is case sensitive. Can you expand and show all of your columns of getData?

Comment: I changed the column from Value to Val thinking the error is referring to Value.Value     .. Its not the case

Comment: Without looking at your data and rdl it is difficult to troubleshoot. Try this and see if it works `=IIF(Fields!Title.Value=1, Fields!Val.Value, 0.0)`

Comment: After you Changed `Value` to `Val` what was the error you were getting?

Comment: I am not getting any errors anymore. However, I am still getting only the first value. I applied the second condition and it works still, but I am still getting the frist value in the DB

Comment: =IIF(Fields!Title.Value=1 And Fields!Day.Value=DateAdd("d",-11,Parameters!WeekEnding.Value), Fields!Val.Value, 0.0)

Comment: So I have multiple columns and this row all will have the same IIF statment. The only difference is the second condition which is the Date parameter. Since I am using calendar dates, each column is a day earlier or later..e.g. -1,-2,-3

Comment: ill send my db pic .. one sec

Comment: Thanks for adding pictures. Can you also show in excel what do you want your output to be? I think you can use matrix and get the data you want.